# Using the height of river to approximate its extreme flood boundaries - terrain analysis in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, analysis, terrain

Using QGIS I'm trying to analyse an area/DEM with this criteria: - heights 10 meter above the river-centerline in both sides of river.

I can do it with the calculation of contours (2m) from DEM and geting the hights of the river-centerline and manually try to draw a line(vector) 10 meters higher than River-Centerline heights (see image below) . But I can't figure out an easy way to filter the boundary area in which the water level of extreme flood cannot reach that hight.

[image]

Anyone have any ideas or thoughts on this problem?

Comment: There is SAGA `Vertical distance to channel network` tool. QGIS has it in the Processing Toolbox, but using it in SAGA GUI would be more comfortable.